# if...else inside a foreach loop php

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I've got the following code to make some submit buttons work.

```
if (isset($_POST["this"])) {
    if ($_SESSION["sentence"] != "") { $_SESSION["sentence"] .= " " ; }
    $_SESSION["sentence"] .= 'This' ;
}

elseif (isset($_POST["my"])) {
    if ($_SESSION["sentence"] != "") { $_SESSION["sentence"] .= " " ; }
    $_SESSION["sentence"] .= 'my' ;
}

elseif (isset($_POST["sentence"])) {
    if ($_SESSION["sentence"] != "") { $_SESSION["sentence"] .= " " ; }
    $_SESSION["sentence"] .= 'sentence' ;
}

else {
    $_SESSION["sentence"] = null;
}
```

**I am trying to make those if...else statements work inside a foreach, but the result does not work.**

```
$sentence='This my sentence';
$words=explode(' ', $sentence);

foreach ($words as $key => $word) {
    
    if (isset($_POST[$word])) {
        if ($_SESSION["sentence"] != "") { $_SESSION["sentence"] .= " " ; }
        $_SESSION["sentence"] .= $word ;
    }
    
}


else {
    $_SESSION["sentence"] = null;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a `foreach/else` in php.

Comment: Why do you need the `else` clause? If the loop isn't entered, nothing will update `$_SESSION["sentence"]`, and it should remain `null` implicitly

Comment: xy problem, really you should fix it that you don't use the array key as the word, just use `name="words[]"` on the form input when you add one, then you can simply implode `$_POST['words']`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tend to disagree, you may end up with `'sentence this my'` or any shuffled sentence, with a simple implode

Comment: @Cid it would depend on the order of the dom, why would it be shuffled?

Comment: "result does not work" -- that's not an error description. Please read [ask], describe what you expected, what you got and why!

Comment: @LawrenceCherone not necessarily, there could be AJAX calls, with the datas built dynamically, the dom order could be different as well, anything could happen. Do you blindly trust users inputs? In the best cases, it will work like a charm. But I've learnt to never expect the best case

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to make `$_SESSION['sentence'] = 'This my sentence'` by checking `$_POST` values.

Your initial variable checking is what is causing the issue. There is not enough information in your code and question to confirm exactly what you want to do.

For example, do you only want `$_SESSION['sentence']` to be a value of `This my sentence` or `null`? Can in be `This my` or `sentence This`?

Taking a guess that you want `This my sentence`, I would approach the problem more like this:

```
$_SESSION['sentence'] = null;

if ((isset($_POST["this"])) && (isset($_POST["my"])) && (isset($_POST["sentence"]))){
  $_SESSION['sentence'] = 'This my sentence';
}
```

The problem with the above code is `isset($_POST['this']` can exist *and* be blank or empty. So you may need to expand to something like:

```
$_SESSION['sentence'] = null;

if ((isset($_POST["this"]) && $_POST["this"]) && 
    (isset($_POST["my"]) && $_POST["my"]) && 
    (isset($_POST["sentence"]) && $_POST["sentence"])){
  $_SESSION['sentence'] = 'This my sentence';
}
```

Now this is getting a bit ugly to read, but would work. If you wanted to make it easier to read, you could do:

```
$_SESSION['sentence'] = null;

if ((isset($_POST["this"])) && (isset($_POST["my"])) && (isset($_POST["sentence"]))){
  if (($_POST["this"]) && ($_POST["my"]) && ($_POST["sentence"])){
    $_SESSION['sentence'] = 'This my sentence';
  }
}
```

If you do not care about the final order of `$_SESSION['sentence']` or even if all values are found, you could do this:

```
$_SESSION['sentence'] = '';
$toCheck = array('This','my','sentence');

foreach($toCheck as $k => $v){
  if ((isset($_POST[$v]) && $_POST[$v]) {
    $_SESSION['sentence'] .= $_POST[$v].' ';
  }
}

$_SESSION['sentence'] = ($_SESSION['sentence']) ? trim($_SESSION['sentence']) : null;
```

With the above option you could end up with any combination or order in `$_SESSION['sentence']`. For example `sentence my` would be be possible.

One last option (and this shows why it is important to be clear in your question), you could do something like this too:

```
$_SESSION['sentence'] = '';
$found = 0;
$toCheck = array('This','my','sentence');

foreach($toCheck as $k => $v){
  if ((isset($_POST[$v]) && $_POST[$v]) {
    $found++;
  }
}

$_SESSION['sentence'] = ($found == 3) ? 'This my sentence' : null;
```